# Asserting argument values of a static method using Powermockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermockito

My simplified class file looks like this:

```
public class NotificationHelper{

public static void sendNotification(String id){
    switch (id) {
        case mobile:
            String message = "Created new account"
            break;
        case email:
            String message = "Hi, An account is created with our website using your email id. This is a notification regarding the same."
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("id is neither phone number nor email id");
    }
    notify(id, message);
}

public static void notify(String id, String message){
    //Code to send notification
}
}
```

I am writing a junit test class to test the method `sendNotification` while mocking the notify method. The goal is to assert values of id and message variables which are passed to `notify` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [spy](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#partial-mocking). With the mockito API:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(NotificationHelper.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(PowerMockRunnerDelegate.DefaultJUnitRunner.class) // for @Rule
public class NotificationHelperTest {
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.spy(NotificationHelper.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendNotificationForEmail() throws Exception {
        NotificationHelper.sendNotification("email");

        PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
        NotificationHelper.notify("email", "Hi, An account is created with our website using your email id. This is a notification regarding the same.");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendNotificationForMobile() throws Exception {
        NotificationHelper.sendNotification("mobile");

        PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
        NotificationHelper.notify("mobile", "Created new account");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendNotification() throws Exception {
        this.expectedException.expect(Exception.class);
        this.expectedException.expectMessage("id is neither phone number nor email id");
        NotificationHelper.sendNotification("foobar");
    }
}
```

Note that I did correct your `NotificationHelper`:

```
public class NotificationHelper {
    public static void sendNotification(String id) throws Exception {
        // TODO: use an enum
        String message;
        switch (id) {
            case "mobile":
                message = "Created new account";
                break;
            case "email":
                message = "Hi, An account is created with our website using your email id. This is a notification regarding the same.";
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("id is neither phone number nor email id");
        }
        notify(id, message);
    }

    public static void notify(String id, String message){
        //Code to send notification
    }
}
```

**Tested with** PowerMock 1.6.2

---

Also note that testing is always *way much easier* if you avoid `static`.